# The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. What is the root cause?

Tags: solidity, remix, abi

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
pragma abicoder v2;

contract test {

    struct Part {
        address payable account;
        uint96 value;
    }

     struct DataV2 {
        Part[] payouts;
        Part[] originFees;
        bool isMakeFill;
    }

    event log(DataV2 data);
    function get(bytes memory data) public {
        emit log(abi.decode(data, (DataV2)));
    }

}
```

data parm for get function = 0x0000000000000000000000001af7a7555263f275433c6bb0b8fdcd231f89b1d70b7f5790f119aa05b581c9e315437cf500449645000000000000000000000001

Comment: The data parameter doesn't seem to be in the correct DataV2 format. DataV2 has two dynamic arrays. abi.decode expect a parameter that follows the [Contract ABI Specification](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html).

Comment: thankyou @Ismael. you are correct.

Comment: If you found a solution it will be nice if you could add it as the answer so the question can be marked as resolved.